# Android EditText remove special formatting and characters (handling "object replacement character" ￼)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

My app is turning special formatting that has been copied into it into "￼". I don't want to allow this, but I've tried a fair few input types and none of the ones I've tried stop it from happening. Ideally I'd like to automatically format out the ￼, but if need be it would be ok to remove it in the background after the user has copied it in.

EditText in layout file:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_recipe_ingredients"
        style="@style/EditorFieldStyle"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:hint="@string/ingredientsHint"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"/>
```

I tried android:imeOptions="flagForceAscii" in here but it didn't work

Example of problem: Copy and pasting:

```
2 aubergines, cut into ½ cm thick slices

8 tbsp olive oil, plus extra for the dish
```

from https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/roasted-vegetable-lasagne

Results in the following getting pasted in

```
2 aubergines

￼

, cut into ½ cm thick slices

8 tbsp olive oil

￼

, plus extra for the dish
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

You can put here any characters that you want to be accepted.